# Discord bot sometimes doesn't add the role to user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

- I'm experiencing a problem adding role to the users using Discord.js V12.5.1. The following code works 80% of the time, but sometimes it just doesn't add the role.
- When I check the audit log, it shows that the bot added the role to the user, but the user can't see the private chats, and if I check the user's role, the role is missing.

Am I doing something wrong?

```js
AddRoleUser: (guid, msg, userId, roleName, reason) => {
        let role = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == roleName);
        let member = msg.guild.members.cache.get(userId);

        if (role && member && !member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
            try {
                member.roles.add(role, reason).catch((error) => logger.error(`UUID: ${guid}, Error: ${error.message}, StackTrace: ${error.stack}`));
                msg.react(reactions.RoleAdd);
                logger.info(`UUID: ${guid}, Role ${roleName} added to member: ${member.displayName}`);
            } catch (error) {
                logger.error(`UUID: ${guid}, Could not add role, Member: ${member.displayName}, Role: ${roleName}, Error: ${error.message}, StackTrace: ${error.stack}`);
            }
        } else {
            logger.warn(`UUID: ${guid}, Could not add role, Member: ${member.displayName}, Role: ${roleName}`);
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

`member.roles.add` returns a promise, but you react and log the results even if this promise is not fulfilled.

You can add a `then()` method and only log and react inside that, you can even check if the returned member has the role now:

```js
try {
  member.roles
    .add(role, reason)
    .then((updatedMember) => {
      // you can check if the member has the role now
      msg.react(reactions.RoleAdd);
      logger.info(`UUID: ${guid}, Role ${roleName} added to member: ${updatedMember.displayName}`);
    })
    .catch((error) => logger.error(`UUID: ${guid}, Error: ${error.message}, StackTrace: ${error.stack}`));

// do you need try-catch? will this ever throw?
} catch (error) {
  logger.error(`UUID: ${guid}, Could not add role, Member: ${member.displayName}, Role: ${roleName}, Error: ${error.message}, StackTrace: ${error.stack}`);
}
```